# Wordpress Woocommerce. I have products that are in promotions. Wanna add a sticker "Promo" for every one product i create with php code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Here is part of code i use for submitting products. With every product i add wanna enable a sticker on product area. I can do it manually from Wordpress edit product but not from here.

```
    $post = array(
                    'post_author' => $user_id,
                    'post_content' => $returnContentDesc,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_title' =>   $productName, //$product->part_num,
                    //$product->is_on_sale()
                    //'post_parent' => $productClass,
                    'post_excerpt' => "$productAvail<br`><b>Гаранция:</b> $transTextWarranty",
                    //'post' => '',
                    'orderby'      => 'menu_order',
                    'hierarchical' => '1',
                    'post_type' => 'product'
                 );

      $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error ); //Create post - product based on array
```

Comment: How you can do it manually from WP edit product… Your question required more details and context… How do you enable this sticker on WP edit product? How is the sticker displayed… So some related code and explanations are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution, setting a sale price manually sets the sticker "Promotion". Will try to test it with the php script. Flatsome theme has "Extra" options then Custom Bubble which the same sticker manually